# Hearthstone Hero Replacers

Tags: hearthstone

Is there a quick way to find all the cards that replace your hero and hero power, like [Magister Dawngrasp](https://playhearthstone.com/en-gb/cards/66848-magister-dawngrasp/) in the crafting interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters works great for this, though it will require two runs:

- Searching for "type:hero" (without quotes) will only show hero cards, such as Magister Dawngrasp.
- Searching for "replace your hero" (without quotes, of course) will show the non-hero cards that can replace the hero, like Renounce Darkness. Jaraxxus was recently converted to a hero card, so no longer has the "replace your hero" text.

Worth noting that, on mobile, Standard/Wild must be selected in Filters before entering a search term.